# Selenium: Stored variable is not considered across test cases while executing test suite from command prompt

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide, selenium-webdriver

I have a test suite with 3 test cases, out of which first test case has all the variables required in the other 2 test cases(something like its a dataset for the test suite)

All this while i was executing testsuites in selenium IDE (Manually loading the test suite in IDE and then run), everything was fine.

But i wanted a report for the test case execution, so now i am using below command to execute the testsuite
java -jar "selenium-server jar path" -htmlSuite "*firefox" "baseurl" "TestSuite path" "Results file Path"

Now the Problem is while executing the test suite from the command propmt, 
variables stored in the First testcase, not considered in the 2nd test case and so on.

So can anybody help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Open archive: selenium-server.jar\core\scripts\
Find selenium-testrunner.js
Find and remove next code from the file:

```
storedVars = new Object();
        storedVars.nbsp = String.fromCharCode(160);
        storedVars.space = ' ';
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply.. But I am not able to find selenium-testrunner.js...as i only have selenium-server.jar file..and I am not using selenium RC..Can you please guide me how can i get this file?

Comment: I modified the selenium-testrunner.js, BUT still the same problem exists.. please help me out to get this right.

Comment: Sorry, you should move that code to the start of 'startTestSuite' function.

Comment: Yes i tried that also but still the same problem...as i see in the below links there are different solutions to this<br>

Comment: Don't know. Moving that code from testcase function to testsuite you setup storedVars only at the start of testsuite. Ensure that you removed that code from test case.

Comment: as i see in the below links there are different solutions to this.. 1.http://jira.openqa.org/browse/SEL-605, 2.http://jira.openqa.org/browse/SRC-712...But unfortunately not working for me :(

Answer (score 1):

This issue is a known bug. So you need to open up the selenium-server.jar or rc jar you have in something like 7zip (what i use) and find the following file:

`selenium-server.jar\core\scripts\selenium-testrunner.js.`

7zip will allow you to update this on the fly, and what you need to do is simply move the following code:

`storedVars = new Object();`
`storedVars.nbsp = String.fromCharCode(160);`
`storedVars.space = ' ';`

from the beginning of the function `startTest` to the beginning of `startTestSuite` function.

Simply moving where the stored variables object is being initialized.

**note** when u select to edit in 7zip it will open in notepad and you will see the code is not formatted, so copy it all and open it in notepad++ or something, then paste back in after the change and save.

you might also have an issue if you are doing this on windows, because at the root of the RC jar is a directory called 'license' and a file called 'LICENSE' and awful windows identifies this as a duplicate file, so before doing all ive said above, change the name of the file 'LICENSE' to something like 'LICENSE_FILE'.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in my java-based code like this:

```
public class ExampleTest{ //main class of all testmodels

private static String valueIneedToBeSendToAllTests;

@Test
  public void test1(){
    // steps of test
    String result = driver.webelement().getText();
    setMyValue(result);
  }

 @Test 
 public void test2(){
    // steps of test
    String whatWasTheTextAgain = getMyValue();

  }


public String getMyValue(){
   return valueIneedToBeSendToAllTests;

  }

public void setMyValue(String valueToSet){
  this.valueIneedToBeSendToAllTests = valueToSet;

 }


}
```

So in repeat:

- Value I need to be preserved is private and **static**
- This value is as value of main class not as one of tests
- The value has setters and getters. In other ways it was crashing for me